# Can I use my phone as a Live-USB and for tethering at the same time?

Tags: live-usb, phone

I understand that you can have an Ubuntu live cd/usb.

I am able to use this Ubuntu live cd/usb, connect my phone to the same computer via usb, switch on wireless + tethering and I end up with a Ubuntu live cd/usb with internet connection.

My question is, is it possible to add Ubuntu live cd/usb into my phones sd card, plus the phone into a computer via usb, get the computer to boot the live cd/usb software directly from my phones sd card, where my phone acts as the Ubuntu live usb, switch on wireless+tethering on my phone, and with the same usb connection on which the phone is passing the live usb to the pc, give the pc an internet connection too?

Is this possible?

If that is not clear.  What I am currently doing is that I have a usb stick and a phone, i.e. 2 items.  the usb stick is to allow any pc to book up from the live image, and then I use my phone to give that booted up pc an internet connection.

What I am asking is, is it possible to stick the usb live image into my phone, so I only need to carry around 1 item, my phone, which can provide the usb live image and the internet connection to any pc which can boot from a usb device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What I am asking is, is it possible to stick the usb live image into my phone, so I only need to carry around 1 item, my phone, which can provide the usb live image and the internet connection to any pc which can boot from a usb device?*

If your phone shows up as a mass-storage device, possibly. (i.e. as a USB SD-card reader). If it *also* shows up as a modem simultaneously, then YES! (I've seen older phones that do one or the other, depending on an internal setting).

You should be able to tell if the first thing is true by connecting the phone before boot, and seeing if it comes up in the list of boot options when you press the appropriate F-key. If it does, let it boot as Live-USB, and see if you can tether!

<sup>Excellent question, BTW!</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will give it a try and report back soon!